# can't get access to admin dasheboard

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel project, I specified 2 guards, 1 for users and 1 for admins.
everything was working properly and today I find out that I couldn't log in to the admin page.
I don't know what happened! I did not change anything!!

when I try to log in as an admin, the login page gets reloads again!

btw, for the case of users, everything works fine!

this is the code

Adminlogincontroller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Admin;

class  AdminLoginController extends Controller 
    {
         use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

   public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware(array('guest:admin','guest:web'))->except('logout');
   }


public function login(Request $request)
{
  // Validate the form data
  $this->validate($request, [
    'email'   => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|min:6'
  ]);

  // Attempt to log the user in
  if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
    // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
    return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
  }

  // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
  return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}

 public function logout(Request $request)
   {
   $this->guard('admin')->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect()->route('AdminLogin');
     }

  public function showLoginForm()
   {
    return view('Admin.admin-login');
   }

   protected function guard()
   {
    return Auth::guard('admin');
  }

   protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
}
```

blade page

```
 <form action="/admin/login" method="post">
             {{csrf_field()}}

            <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">email
      </i>
      <input id="icon_prefix" name="email" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix" style="color:#fff;">E-Mail</label>
    </div>

           <div class="input-field col s12">
       <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
      <input id="icon_prefix" name="password" type="password" 
      class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix" style="color:#fff;">Mot de passe</label>
    </div>
            <p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" />
    <label for="filled-in-box" >Se rappeler de moi?</label>

    <a href="" class="right"> Mot de passe oublié </a>
   </p>
               <div class="row">
              <div class="col s12">

             <input type="submit" class="btn hoverable purple white-text" style="margin-top:30px;" value="connexion">

</div></div>





         </form>
```

routes:php

```
    Route::post('/admin/login', 'Admin\AdminLoginController@login');
Route::get('/admin/logout', 'Admin\AdminLoginController@logout');

 Route::get('/admin', 'Admin\AdminController@show')->name('dashboard')
```

Comment: Perhaps there is an error log output that has some clues? It's unlikely that it's a code issue if it just suddenly stopped working without any modifications.

Comment: I really have no idea...
I feel I got stuck right now...
last time I just added some admin cruds, tested them, then I uploaded the project..
and now as you see I got this unexpected issue :(

Comment: Where is the login method?

Comment: You don't have `'Admin\AdminLoginController@login'` defined at all.

Comment: May be your credentials doesn't match. You Can use dd($validator->errors());
on admin login page to debug;

Comment: Guys I modified the code by adding login method and I got the same error  but believe me  it wasn't defined before and the redirection was working ok..
I'm working on this project for more than 2 months now :(

Comment: Try some logging within the login function. `Log::info($request->all());`, and then add some lines within the attempt and after it to see where it's hitting. Check in `storage/logs/` for the log file.

Comment: Use the guard that works, then use this to separate roles/permissions - https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: @AtefRihane what Midlleware do you have on your dashboard route (via artisan route:list)? Does your admin account also have user role/permisssion?

Comment: @Bart : I have auth:admin in the dasheboard route...
well I didn't find any solution except stepping back to an old version from the project..
till now couldn't find out the issue..

Comment: @AtefRihane sad to hear that, cause sooner or later, you will hit this issue again. And moving backwards is definitely, not moving into right direction... At least try to compare these versions, maybe you'll find something enlightening...

Comment: I know that my friend :(, this is my graduation project btw and due  to the shortage of the time I couldn't completly concentrate on fixing it , because I have a report to write at the meantime...
that sucks really :(